# how to bind int property value to ObjectDataProvider ConstructorParameter

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

MyView.xaml has MyViewModel as DataContext. MyViewModel takes an int parameter. So, how do i setup datacontext to MyViewModel with a parameter. I need to bind an int property from codebehind in MyView.xaml as shown below:

MyView.xaml

```
<dxr:DXRibbonWindow.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="vm:MyViewModel" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>                
            <sys:Int32>Id</sys:Int32>
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</dxr:DXRibbonWindow.DataContext>
```

MyView.xaml.cs (codebehind)

```
public int Id {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly what you asked, but it's just a different approach that i use everytime i set the datacontext in xaml.

I usually define a loaded event for my viewmodel like the following:

```
public void LoadParams(int Id)
{
    this.Id = Id;
}
```

It's a very simple solution. You just need to call this method from your user control (you can do this also on the `Loaded event`). In your code behind you can do something like this:

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyViewmodel instance = this.DataContext as MyViewmodel;
    instance.LoadParameters(Id);
}
```